# Energy required for computation

Tags: entropy, computational-physics

Is there a way to quantify a theoretical value for the minimum amount of energy required for arbitrary computation? Can an infinite amount of computation occur in a finite amount of time?

Comment: Do you mean like the energy in terms of electric current? Or something else? And are you considering computers in the second question? Or are you viewing the "universe as a computer" here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle